# Why can AB people receive blood from A, B or O?

Tags: blood-group

AB people don't have agglutinins anti A or anti B so it might seem they can receive any type of blood. But if the donator is A for example, it's own blood will have agglutinins anti B that will agglutinate the AB blood. So why can AB people receive blood from non AB people?